What should I do to transfer C union struct to C# struct, that let them have same kind in memory
This is my struct in C:
typedef struct s1 {
    int i;
    union {
        s2 u1;
        s3 u2;
    }
}

typedef struct s2
{
    int w[10];    
}

typedef struct s3
{
    int w[10];
}

This is my code in C#:
public struct s2
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    int[] w;
}

public struct s3
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    int[] w;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct s4
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    int i;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    s2 s2;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    s3 s3;
}

When I use the struct, it throws an error about [an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field].
I use a byte to hold this place, then get the byte pointer to convert s2 or s3 struct; like this [ byte  s3;];  but it's so bad to use.
Is there any other way to specify this type directly?
I have no idea, I tried to add attribute UnmanagedType.IUnknown and  some others, but it still does not work.

You might want to checkout fixed sized buffers .

C# 12 introduced Inline arrays serving a similar purpose as fixed size buffers.

Be careful with C int's. They aren't always 32 bits, but C# ints are. Whenever doing interop, it's wise to be explicit wrt to the size of scalars.

@JonasH Olivier is right in that when possible (which requires specific runtime support), inline arrays are much easier to understand and work with than fixed buffers (even though they fundamentally do the same thing); fixed buffers are worth mentioning as a fallback when you need to use older runtimes, though

@JonasH I used   to  use  fixed sized buffer with  unsafe   tag;like  public  fixed  byte  bt[10];   ,but  when  invoke  the  extern method  ,it's  throw  error about  marshal  data,  i  didn't  know  what happen to marshal data;

@OlivierJacot-Descombes   my dotnet version is netcore6.0  ，and for some reason ，change to  the  higher  version  is can't  be  ture;so  emmm.

@nuub that (.NET 6) would have been great to know earlier; I've added a "fixed buffers" approach to my answer, since "inline arrays" don't exist until .NET 8; I also strongly suggest "update to .NET 8" - is there a reason blocking you? (genuine question - I'm in the .NET team, and I'm interested in blocking problems)

Given that s2 and s3 are both int[10] why do you need separate structs anyway?

@MarcGravell Because it can take some time to change the framework, we can't afford to take that risk

@Charlieface well,it's  just a example,to  explain the type of problem I'm experiencing。

@nuub the change from 6 to 8 or 9 should be very negligible (and in general should be an improvement in stability) - but I do understand risk-averse nature of these things

You can't use arrays (reference types) here; however, an inline array (which is similar to a "fixed buffer") would work nicly:
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.SizeOf<s4>());
// ^^^ 44 = 11 integers, as expected

var obj = new s4();
obj.s2[3] = 13;
Console.WriteLine(obj.s3[3]); // 13

[InlineArray(10)]
public struct s2
{
    // this just defines the type for the inline array
    private int w;
}
[InlineArray(10)]
public struct s3
{
    // this just defines the type for the inline array
    private int w;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct s4
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    int i;
    // changed accessibility to test
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public s2 s2;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public s3 s3;
}

However: honestly, given that s2 and s2 have the same shape... I'm really not sure what the point of having them as separate types is here. Just having a single type and single field would seem to be fine.

If you're not using .NET 8 or later; fixed buffers:
public unsafe struct s2
{
    private fixed int w[10];
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (int* ptr = w)
            {
                return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(ptr, 10)[index];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            fixed (int* ptr = w)
            {
                new Span<int>(ptr, 10)[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
public unsafe struct s3
{
    private fixed int w[10];
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (int* ptr = w)
            {
                return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(ptr, 10)[index];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            fixed (int* ptr = w)
            {
                new Span<int>(ptr, 10)[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}


this  code  just  fake，actually, in my project, there is a struct that has a uion  struct in it, and the uion  struct contain other structs that contain uion   and arrays.it's a relatively large structure

ok,I'll try later,thanks
